# ffmpeg multiple files at once

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have this FFmepg script in a batch file:

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4*") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -y -c:v prores_ks -profile:v proxy -pix_fmt yuv422p10le -vendor ap10 -bits_per_mb 8000  -vf "scale=1920:1080" -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48K "..\%%~na.mov"
```

It renders all `.mp4` files in the folder it is in to `.mov` and drops it in the previous folder.

The issue is that I wanted to optimize the process and take more advantage of the hardware, rendering 4 videos at the same time, but I didn't find a way to write the script so that it analyzes how many `.mp4` there are in the folder and divides these files into 4 ffmpeg instances.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Is the `prores_ks` multithreaded or not? If it is, there's little gain to expect by running several ffmpeg commands concurrently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To optimize the process and take advantage of your hardware by rendering multiple files at once, you can use the start command in Windows to run multiple instances of the ffmpeg command concurrently. Here's an example of how you could modify your script to do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set counter=0
set max_instances=4

for %%a in ("*.mp4*") do (
  set /a counter+=1
  set /a counter_mod=!counter! %% !max_instances!
  if !counter_mod! equ 0 (
    start "" "ffmpeg" -i "%%a" -y -c:v prores_ks -profile:v proxy -pix_fmt yuv422p10le -vendor ap10 -bits_per_mb 8000  -vf "scale=1920:1080" -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48K "..\%%~na.mov"
  ) else (
    ffmpeg -i "%%a" -y -c:v prores_ks -profile:v proxy -pix_fmt yuv422p10le -vendor ap10 -bits_per_mb 8000  -vf "scale=1920:1080" -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48K "..\%%~na.mov"
  )
)
```

This script will start up to 4 instances of ffmpeg at a time, with each instance processing one file. When an instance finishes processing a file, it will start processing the next one until all of the files have been processed.

```
cmd /v:on /c "your_script.bat"
```

Comment: Wow!
Excellent solution, it was exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much for the help and detailed explanation, this will help me a lot.

Comment: Your Welcome...

Comment: @DariushGavari You never answered my question if the prores_ks codec was multithreaded or not, so I tested: it is multithreaded. And on my 4 cores machine it uses 4 threads by default, no need to specify the number of threads (many video codecs run multiple threads by default). So you won't gain a lot (if anything at all) by forcing the threads or running multiple instances.

Comment: *"This option specifies the number of threads to use for decoding and encoding"* : assuming that the decoder and the encoder are multithreaded, and when it's the case they generally run multiple threads by default.

Comment: @PierU i edit my code and check it if working tell us. thanks